# Why ubuntu doesn't run a bin file?

Tags: command-line, tar, binary

I'm trying to install a software on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. After downloading the `tar.gz` file, I extracted the files with the command:

```
tar -xvf CCS6.1.0.00104_linux.tar.gz
```

Then I entrered the extracted folder and what I found inside is this:

```
README_FIRST.txt
baserepo  
ccs_setup_6.1.0.00104.bin  
featurerepo 
timestamp.txt
artifacts.jar
binary
content.jar 
features
```

In particular, when I type `ll` the `ccs_setup_6.1.0.00104.bin` is displayed in green with a `*` next to it, meaning the file is executable, but, when I try to launch it using:

```
./ccs_setup_6.1.0.00104.bin
```

nothing happens and I don't know why.

Does someone know the reason? Thank you.

Comment: Aren't there any instructions for this - what does the `README` say? The instructions should tell you which file should be run etc.

Comment: No it just says to "run the bin file" very generally.

Comment: Please include output of `stat ./ccs_setup_6.1.0.00104.bin`

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provide a link to the download of that `tar.gz`-file.

Comment: @mook765 Probably it's this file: https://dr-download.ti.com/software-development/ide-configuration-compiler-or-debugger/MD-J1VdearkvK/6.1.0.00104/CCS6.1.0.00104_linux.tar.gz, can be downloaded from this page: https://www.ti.com/tool/download/CCSTUDIO/6.1.0.00104

Comment: I found out that the file is a 32-bit executable. It won't run by default on 64-bit system without 32-bit libraries installed. @Vittorio you probably need to install them.